# Swift class extension with protocol vs conforming to protocol

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

In [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/78550/beginning-ios-collection-views-swift-part-1) tutorial, the author uses `extension FlickrPhotosViewController: UITextFieldDelegate` and then implements the protocol method. I have tested and the author could just as easily have done `class FlickrPhotosViewController: UICollectionViewController, UITextFieldDelegate` and implemented the methods in the class. Only difference I can see is that it makes it easier to read and understand. Is this a design style or something?

Comment: It's an easier code layout to read, makes for nice semantic separation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a design style or something

Very much so. It is normal style to separate a class into multiple extensions, each expressing that class's adoption of one or more related protocols. But this separation has no *functional* meaning; the class *could* have been expressed without that separation.

Answer (score 1):

It is better coding.

You should not combine text field delegates and view controllers in the same file.